# AppDelegateファイルのエラー

Tags: swift, xcode

プログラムを実行し、ビューが表示された時に、いきなりAppDelegate.swiftのファイルにエラーが出てしまいました。エラーの位置とエラーの詳細は

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {//Thread1: signal SIGABRT

このようになっております。
コンパイル、ビルドはうまくいっているのですが、ここで考えられる原因はなんでしょうか？
ご教授お願いします。
ちなみにswift2.0 Xcode7.1.1を使用しております。

Comment: それは運悪くメインループに戻ったところで停止してしまっているだけで、実際の原因は他のところにあります。「Swift Error Breakpoint」や「Exception Breakpoint」を設定するとエラーの発生した箇所で止めることができる可能性があります。もしエラーの発生した箇所で止めることができれば原因の究明に役立ちます。もしくは、Xcodeのコンソールに何か手がかりになるようなログは出力されていませんか？それも無ければ、ビューまでは表示されているということなので、最初に表示されるビューコントローラの`viewDidLoad`などにブレイクポイントを置いて、エラーの起こる行を1ステップずつ見ていくことになります。